# backend stack for React native

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, graphql, strapi

Thinking of creating an APP in react native that does the following:

1. Minimal social media w/ feed, pictures, comments, likes, profile
   etc.
2. Redender locations from a Database on a map
3. store those locations in a database for quick queries
4. Make API calls from third party source that updates the Database,
   database then updates the map.
5. Messaging / group chat
6. Search Database
7. secure
8. handle payments
9. Authentication

I have been looking around and there so much information I don't know where to start. There nodes.js, express, hapi, straps,django......

Please can you guys provide some STACK suggestions and reason to why??

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not see why you need to re-invent the wheel. 
Most of the features you need can be implemented via some chat platforms like [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/). You can use this backend and implement only client-side. I believe it should be easier for you.

The only feature left is payments. This part depends on what you need to use for payments.

If you need to implement in-app purchases and are going to publish your app in AppStore, then you need to set those purchases via Apple. 
Otherwise, your app can be rejected by Apple.

Here is some info about [in-app purchases](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/).

For Android here is a useful [article](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/in-app-purchases) on setting in-app purchases via Google Play.